# Create Task group is disabled for Powershell tasks

Tags: azure-devops

I m unable to create a task group for Powershell tasks in VSTS . It works for rest of the tasks except PS.

[image: Create Taskgroup disabled]

Please advice !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m able to achieve it.  Please ignore.

I had to make sure that Inline script has no errors and my release def is saved. !